# Не срабатывает Php скрипт отправки в телеграм

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не срабатывает скрипт php с отправкой формы, открывается пустое окно. На локальном сервере всё прекрасно работает, данные отправляются. Хост php поддерживает, создал файл info.php, всё ок, срабатывает и выводит информацию.

Как я понимаю, дело в $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

Я не phpшник, в общем это можно исправить или поискать другие методы? ($sendToTelegram)

Вот лог ошибок :

**Warning: fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error in /home/vol1_4/ezyro.com/ezyro_32805238/htdocs/php/sendform.php on line 23

Warning: fopen(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/vol1_4/ezyro.com/ezyro_32805238/htdocs/php/sendform.php on line 23

Warning: fopen(https://api.telegram.org/bot56xxxxx:AAE_C4nzRFv4UGYMiWgqpD7xr_2ZsAlS1SM/sendMessage?chat_id=-7xxxxx&parse_mode=html&text=**Сообщение с**  webdevguy%0A**Имя:**  %0A**Email:**  %0A %0A): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/vol1_4/ezyro.com/ezyro_32805238/htdocs/php/sendform.php on line 23**

````
//Сбор данных из полей формы. 
<?php
//Сбор данных из полей формы. 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$email = $_POST['mail']; 

$token = "xxxx463163:AAE_C4nzRFv4UGYMiWgqpD7xr_xxxxxx"; // токен
$chat_id = "-78967xxxx"; // ID группы,
$sitename = "xxxxxx"; //название сайта

$arr = array(

  'Заявка с ' => $sitename,
  'Имя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Телеграм: ' => $email
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

?>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("form").submit(function() {
        var form_data = jQuery(this).serialize(); 
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "php/sendform.php", 
            data: form_data,
            success: swal({
                title: "Thanks!",
                type: "success",
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2000
            })
        });
        $(this).find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', true);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});```
````

Comment: Line 23 это :  $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что у вас на хостинге не поддерживается HTTPS для **fopen** и тому подобных операций.

По идее можно переписать на использование curl - но нужно уточнять в поддержке хостинга будет ли оно работать или нет. Возможно что тоже не будет.

ДА и вообще лучше обратиться с этой проблемой в поддержку хостинга. Возможно у них уже есть готовое решение или рекомендация что надо делать в такой ситуации.